# Convert JS Array to a Sass list

Tags: javascript, sass

I am using gulp in a node/pug project. I was wondering if there was a way to convert a JS array to a Sass list. Currently i am using Gulp sass to pipe the array

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/Views/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass()) //using gulp-sass
        .pipe(replace('myArray', MyArray)) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/Views/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true 
        }))
});
```

And in scss

```
$combinations: MyArray;

@for $i from 0 to length($combinations) {
    $class : nth($combinations, $i+1);
    .color-#{$class)} {
        background-image: url($media2 + nth($combinations, $i+1) + ".jpg")
    } 
}
```

However the loop will never run correctly since combinations is an Array and not a Sass list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of variable replace, use the sassVariables. please follow the below:

```
var sassVariables = require('gulp-sass-variables');
gulp.task('sass', function() {
        return gulp.src('app/Views/scss/**/*.scss')

            .pipe(sassVariables({
                   $combinations: MyArray
                 })) 
            .pipe(sass()) //using gulp-sass
            .pipe(gulp.dest('app/Views/css'))
            .pipe(browserSync.reload({
                stream: true 
            }))
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, It did not work, however you put me on the right path. I used gulp-sass-vars instead of sassVariables, which is injecting my array as a sass list in the .scss file.

Comment: Please declare the var sassVariables = require('gulp-sass-variables') and use